# TSQL - Select from table with multiple join paths

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

That title is not very good, so consider the following. I have five tables:

```
User {
    Id,
    ProfileId        // -> Profiles.Id
}

Profile {
    Id
}

ProfilePermissionSets {
    ProfileId        // -> Profiles.Id
    PermissionSetId  // -> PermissionSets.Id
}

UserPermissionSets {
    UserId           // -> Users.Id
    PermissionSetId  // -> PermissionSets.Id
}

PermissionSets {
    Id
}

Permissions {
    Id,
    PermissionSetId  // -> PermissionSets.Id
}
```

And I want get all of the permissions for a user that are directly linked to it or indirectly through the profile. The not-quite-there SQL I've come up with so far is this:

```
SELECT  [Pe].[Controller],
        [Pe].[Action]
FROM    [PermissionSets] AS [PS]
        JOIN [UserPermissionSets] AS [UPS]
            ON ([UPS].[PermissionSetId] = [PS].[Id])
        JOIN [Users] AS [U]
            ON ([U].[Id] = [UPS].[UserId])
        JOIN [Profiles] AS [P]
            ON ([P].[Id] = [U].[ProfileId])
        JOIN [ProfilePermissionSets] AS [PPS]
            ON ([PPS].[ProfileId] = [P].[Id])
        JOIN [Permissions] AS [Pe]
            ON ([Pe].[PermissionSetId] = [PS].[Id])
WHERE   [U].[Id] = 4;
```

It returns back a correct count of rows, but it's repeating the controller or action over and over, so it's wrong. I'm hoping someone can help me correct it to show all of the distinct permission sets for the user. Ideally, I'd like to also change it so that it's all discovered starting at the user because that is what I have access to in the method I need to do this (the object is an Entity Framework class named `User` and will be browsed using LINQ).

**UPDATED** because I forgot that I *really* wanted the permissions not the permission sets.

Comment: Are you just looking for `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Not sure, I know enough SQL to cause problems for myself, lol.

Comment: Does a user always have at least one entry in the _UserPermissionSets_ Table? If not, you will only retrieve users having an entry in _UserPermissionSets_ or in _UserPermissionSets_ and _Permissions_. You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then.

Comment: @schlonzo No, the user may not have any entries through the `UserPermissionSets` table. The only guaranteed entries would come through the `Profiles` table.

Comment: Then I think a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and `GROUP BY`is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT  [Pe].[Controller],
        [Pe].[Action]
FROM    [Users] AS [U]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserPermissionSets] AS [UPS]
            ON ([UPS].[UserId] = [U].[Id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProfilePermissionSets] AS [PPS]
            ON ([PPS].[ProfileId] = [U].[ProfileId])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Permissions] AS [Pe]
            ON ([Pe].[PermissionSetId] = [UPS].[PermissionSetId])
            OR ([Pe].[PermissionSetId] = [PPS].[PermissionSetId])
WHERE   [U].[Id] = 4;
```

Comment: That only produces the directly related permissions and excludes the indirectly related permissions from the profile.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c, query changed, plz chk now

Comment: I refined your example to be `DISTINCT` and it gave me the results I wanted. I then made it into a view and made a fake relationship to it from the `User` class in the EF implementation. Works great and reduced the queries to just one vs my LINQ implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, messing around on LINQPad, I came up with this as far as the LINQ query:

```
user.PermissionSets.Union(user.Profile.PermissionSets).SelectMany(
    ps =>
        ps.Permissions.Select(
            p =>
                p.Controller + "." + p.Action));
```

And it produces what I want, BUT it does it by composing the results of a bunch of SQL queries. The biggest impact comes from profiles that have multiple permission sets, like say the Administrator. I don't think there's a way around it, and I only have a `User` object to work with, so I'm ok with the excess SQL queries, at least for now.